# es posible lanzar un assembly si mi cabecera esta dañada o borrada?

Tags: c#

Cuando cargo un assembly en memoria una vez borrada mi cabecera siempre me muestra el mismo error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has
been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationExcept
ion: The type initializer for 'T???????????????????' threw an exception. ---> Sy
stem.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Ma
nagementPath' threw an exception. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of
 type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(IPrincipal principal, StackCrawlMark
& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start()
   at System.Management.MTAHelper.InitWorkerThread()
   at System.Management.MTAHelper.CreateInMTA(Type type)
   at System.Management.ManagementPath.CreateWbemPath(String path)
   at System.Management.ManagementPath..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.ManagementScope._Clone(ManagementScope scope, Identifier
ChangedEventHandler handler)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher..ctor(ManagementScope scope, Ob
jectQuery query, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher..ctor(String queryString)
   at T???????????????????..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at T???????????????????.get_Is64Bit()
   at ????????????????????.????????????????????()
   at ????????????????????.????????????????????()
   at ????????????????????.Main(String[] args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments,
 Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Objec
t[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invoke
Attr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at skip.Program.RunInternal(Byte[] encode, String pass)
   at skip.Program.Main()
```

Lo primero que hago borro mi cabecera:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr ZeroMemory(IntPtr addr, IntPtr size);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr VirtualProtect(IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, IntPtr flNewProtect, ref IntPtr lpflOldProtect);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        public static void EraseHeader()
        {
            IntPtr address = GetModuleHandle(null);
            IntPtr dwOld = default(IntPtr);
            VirtualProtect(address, (IntPtr)4096, (IntPtr)0x40, ref dwOld);
            ZeroMemory(address, (IntPtr)4096);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            EraseHeader();
            while(true)
                Console.WriteLine("");
            //Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Y luego cargo mi assembly:

```
Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(Buffer);
object[] parameters = new object[1]; 
exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

Sin embargo siempre me muestra el mismo error:

```
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Mi pregunta es a parte de que no entiendo el error, es posible lanzar una assembly si la cabecera de mi ejecutable fuese borrada o dañada. Estaba probando simplemente para comprobar si era posible pero veo que no.

Comment: `--- End of inner exception stack trace ---` no es un error, es un mensaje que te indica que el mensaje de error para una excepción termina ahí. El error se indica al principio del stack: `Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has
been thrown by the target of an invocation.` Te recomendaría que editaras la publicación para indicar que la pregunta es lo de lanzar un assembly en lugar del mensaje de error (que realmente no es mensaje de error)

Comment: Buenas. En realidad hasta lo que tengo entendido no seria posible.